# Prove increase of expected value

Tags: probability, derivatives

I am trying to prove the following:

> For $x$ distributed on $X=[a,b]\subset \mathbb{R}^+$ with the cumulative distribution function $F(\cdot)$ s.t. $F'(x)=f(x)>0\ \forall x\in X$:
>
> $E[x\mid x\leq\bar{x}]$ is strictly increasing in $\bar{x}\ \forall\bar{x}\in(a,b)$, where $E[\cdot]$ denotes the expected value.

My current approach is:

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial\bar{x}} E[x\mid x\leq\bar{x}]
= \frac{\partial}{\partial\bar{x}}\frac{\int_a^\bar{x}x\cdot f(x)\mathrm{d}x}{\underbrace{\int_a^\bar{x}f(x)\mathrm{d}x}_{=F(\bar{x})}}
= \frac{\left(\bar{x}\cdot f(\bar{x})\right)\cdot F(\bar{x})-\overbrace{F'(\bar{x})}^{=f(\bar{x})}}{(F(\bar{x}))^2}=\frac{f(\bar{x})}{F(\bar{x})}\left(\bar{x}-\frac{1}{F(\bar{x})}\right)
$$

which is strictly greater than zero if and only if $\bar{x}>\frac{1}{F(\bar{x})}$, but since  $F(\bar{x})\in (0,1]$ this would require that $\bar{x}>1$, which does not necessarily hold.

Any help on where I went wrong would be greatly appreciated. If information is missing, please let me know.

Comment: I can identify $v$, $du$, and $v^2$ in $\displaystyle \mathrm d\left(\frac{u}{v}\right) = \frac{v\,\mathrm du - u\,\mathrm dv}{v^2}$ but how did $u\,\,\mathrm dv$ work out to be what you claim it is? Shouldn't it be something like $\displaystyle \left(\int_a^{\bar{x}} xf(x)dx\right)\cdot f(\bar{x})$?

Comment: You made mistake in taking derivative. You should get $\frac {f(\bar x)}{F(\bar x)}(\bar x - E[x|x\le \bar x])$. Then the result immediately follows,.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial \bar{x}} \frac{\int_a^{\bar{x}} x \cdot f(x) \mathrm{d}x}{\int_a^\bar{x}f(x)\mathrm{d}x} = \frac{(\bar{x}\cdot f(\bar{x})\cdot F(\bar{x})-\left(\int_a^{\bar{x}} x \cdot f(x) \mathrm{d}x\right)\cdot f(\bar{x})}{F^2(\bar{x})}$$

Since $f(x)>0$ for all $x \in (a,b)$ and $0<a<\bar{x}$, we have $\int_a^{\bar{x}} x \cdot f(x) \mathrm{d}x < \bar{x} \int_a^{\bar{x}} \cdot f(x) \mathrm{d}x = \bar{x}F(\bar{x})$

So, $(\bar{x}\cdot f(\bar{x})\cdot F(\bar{x})-\left(\int_a^{\bar{x}} x \cdot f(x) \mathrm{d}x\right)\cdot f(\bar{x}) > (\bar{x}\cdot f(\bar{x})\cdot F(\bar{x})- (\bar{x} F(\bar{x}))\cdot f(\bar{x}) = 0$

Therefore, the fraction is the ratio of two positive numbers and you are done.

Comment: great, thanks! so I failed at the derivative...